# Why does C++'s qualified name lookup accept repeating a class name?

Tags: c++

```
struct A
{
    static void foo() {}
};

namespace B
{
    void bar() {}
}

void run()
{
   A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::A::foo(); // compiles
   B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::B::bar(); // doesn't compile
}
```

I'm intrigued by the fact that `A::A::A...` is valid code. I would expect a compilation error just like I get for `B::B::...`. Anything in the lookup rules that can explain that?